# Form submission using Jquery: NULL is submitted

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a problem with form submission. The form is built using Jquery and then the data is passed to another page, where I

```
<%String userEmail="blabla@bla.com";%>
<script>
$form = $("<form id='frm' action='submit.jsp' method='post'>");
$form.append(" <input id='userEmail' name='userEmail' class='input' value=<%=userEmail%> type='hidden'  /> ");
$form.append("Enter a barcode: "); 
$form.append(" <input id='bcode' name='bcode' class='input' type='number' size='12' required/> <br/> ");
$form.append('Enter a price: ');
$form.append("<input id='price' class='input' name='price' type='number' size='12' required/> <br/></form>");
$("#form").append($form);
```

Then, when "Submit" button (with id="submit") is pressed:

```
$(".next").on("click", "#submit", function () {  
$("#frm").submit();
});
</script>
```

Then in submit.jsp:

```
<%
String price = request.getParameter("price"); //problem
String barcode = request.getParameter("bcode"); //problem
String userEmail = request.getParameter("userEmail");
form frm = new form();
insRes = frm.insertEvent(price, barcode, userEmail); 
%>
```

The problem is that I get NULL instead of "price" and "barcode". The email field is OK.

P.S. Yes, I'm very new to programming, study by myself using books and google. 
Searched for the similar problem here, didn't find. Sorry if I missed it.

### EDIT:

I've serialized the form before submission, and the only thing was submitted is email. Why? Does it matter that I form the form with jquery?

Comment: can you try chainging `value=<%=userEmail%>` to `value='<%=userEmail%>'`

Comment: It doesn't change the result.

Comment: Are you putting some values into the inputs ?? :)

Comment: Sure! Before submission I have functions that check if those fields are OK for submission (not empty, are numbers and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was causing the problem.
After a user enters a barcode and a price I check if the inputs are OK, and if they are OK, I prevent user from changing them by adding:

```
$("#price").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#bcode").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

When I commented those two lines, the problem was solved.

Sorry for not putting the whole code - I didn't think it matters.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have misused something.
I have corrected your code and data is sent. Of course you should put some value in inputs before sending form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var email = 'blabla@bla.com';

var $form = $("<form id='frm' action='submit.jsp' method='post'>");
$form.append(" <input id='userEmail' name='userEmail' class='input' value="+ email +" type='hidden'  /> ");
$form.append("Enter a barcode: "); 
$form.append(" <input id='bcode' name='bcode' class='input' type='number' size='12' required/> <br/> ");
$form.append('Enter a price: ');
$form.append("<input id='price' class='input' name='price' type='number' size='12' required/> <br/></form>");
$("#form").append($form);


    $(document).on("click", ".next", function () {
        console.log('send');
        $("#frm").submit();
    });
})
```

[See it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/333/)

Comment: First when providing an answer explain what changes you make. Second the question mention that EMAIL is working. So your answer doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: @Lorenzo, what is your problem? I'm trying to help - I've written working code on js and have show it in fiddle. Of course it differs from question - I can't use asp in Fiddle and it's the only change.

Comment: Can't see it's working (I mean the link). After submission I have to move to submit.jsp to see if it's really passed the data, and there is no such page. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can see network in Chrome and there you will see Form data that was sent - all three inputs.

Comment: I've updated fiddle - now it alerts data that is to be sent but does not actually send it

Comment: @ProstoTrader so you think that your answer is resolving his issue ? by changing var email = 'blabla@bla.com'; and $(document).on("click", ".next" ... I repeat myself but the question mention that email is working so the form is submitting.

Comment: @Lorenzo, it just means that code, posted in question is not what he really has in project. The best way to find bug is to compare it with working code, which I submitted.

Comment: @Lorenzo, see his edits - he DID had another code on his page, which was not show to us and there was the bug.